# Code optimization python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

I wrote the below function to estimate the orientation from a 3 axes accelerometer signal (X,Y,Z)

```
X.shape
Out[4]: (180000L,)
Y.shape
Out[4]: (180000L,)
Z.shape
Out[4]: (180000L,)

def estimate_orientation(self,X,Y,Z):

    sigIn=np.array([X,Y,Z]).T
    N=len(sigIn)
    sigOut=np.empty(shape=(N,3))
    sigOut[sigOut==0]=None
    i=0
    while i<N:
        sigOut[i,:] = np.arccos(sigIn[i,:]/np.linalg.norm(sigIn[i,:]))*180/math.pi
        i=i+1

    return sigOut
```

Executing this function with a signal of 180000 samples takes quite a while (~2.2 seconds)... I know that it is not written in a "pythonic way"... Could you help me to optimize the execution time?

Thanks!

Comment: 180000,3   I have edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Starting approach**

One approach following an usage of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), would be like so -

```
np.arccos(sigIn/np.linalg.norm(sigIn,axis=1,keepdims=1))*180/np.pi
```

**Further optimization - I**

We could use `np.einsum` to replace `np.linalg.norm` part. Thus :

```
np.linalg.norm(sigIn,axis=1,keepdims=1)
```

could be replaced by :

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',sigIn,sigIn))[:,None]
```

**Further optimization - II**

Further boost could be brought in with [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide), which works really well with huge arrays and with operations involving `trigonometrical` functions. In our case that would be `arcccos`. So, we will use the `einsum` part as used in the previous optimization section and then use `arccos` from `numexpr` on it.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
import numexpr as ne

pi_val = np.pi
s = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',signIn,signIn))[:,None]
out = ne.evaluate('arccos(signIn/s)*180/pi_val')
```

### Runtime test

Approaches -

```
def original_app(sigIn):
    N=len(sigIn)
    sigOut=np.empty(shape=(N,3))
    sigOut[sigOut==0]=None
    i=0
    while i<N:
        sigOut[i,:] = np.arccos(sigIn[i,:]/np.linalg.norm(sigIn[i,:]))*180/math.pi
        i=i+1
    return sigOut

def broadcasting_app(signIn):
    s = np.linalg.norm(signIn,axis=1,keepdims=1)
    return np.arccos(signIn/s)*180/np.pi

def einsum_app(signIn):
    s = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',signIn,signIn))[:,None]
    return np.arccos(signIn/s)*180/np.pi

def numexpr_app(signIn):
    pi_val = np.pi
    s = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',signIn,signIn))[:,None]
    return ne.evaluate('arccos(signIn/s)*180/pi_val')
```

Timings -

```
In [115]: a = np.random.rand(180000,3)

In [116]: %timeit original_app(a)
     ...: %timeit broadcasting_app(a)
     ...: %timeit einsum_app(a)
     ...: %timeit numexpr_app(a)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.38 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.85 ms per loop

In [117]: 1380/4.85 # Speedup number
Out[117]: 284.5360824742268
```

**`280x`** speedup there!